# 2D arrays recursively filled

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have to fill array 10x10 with numbers

```
{{100,50,25...}, {50,25,12...}}
```

and so on recursively

I got `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` and I know exactly where do I get this but can't find solution to fix things. If I fix them, I don't get the results.

Here is my code :

```
public static int [][] createArray(int [][] a) {
    int[][] f = new int[a.length][a.length];
    f[0][0] = 100;
    fillArray(a, 0, 1);
    return a;
}


public static void fillArray(int [][]a, int row,int col) {
    a[0][0]=100;
    if(row<a.length){
        if(col<a[row].length){
            a[row][col]= a[0][col-1]/2;
            fillArray(a, row, col+1);
        }
        else{
            fillArray(a,row+1,col-1);
        }
    }
}
```